# x-scrolling on webpage during mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So i made a bootstrap 3 site for a local chapter of trout unlimited to help them out.

Basically the site is fine in regular browsers etc... but when viewing from a mobile phone there is a little bit of play left to right...  overflow-x is set to hidden. I cant seem to figure out why this is happening. I was thinking it had something to do with the google calendar iframe, so i reduced the size to no avail.

SOME ONE DROP SOME KNOWLEDGE ON ME !!! HELP !

Thanks in advance.

[Live Site](http://www.bctu304.org)

Comment: It happens in Chrome too. There's something that's too big for its container.

Comment: The  calendar has been wrapped inside a nav with `margin: 20px;` replace that with `padding:20px;`

Comment: Thanks will test and post back.

Answer (score 0):

You manipulate the padding of the containers using the .section* classes.

remove the padding-rules from .section1, .section2, ... and the play will disappear.

If you really need this padding, apply it on the individual cols.